# TextField Maximum text entered Validate from a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to write a common method where i can use it in all classes in the project.

This method will accept a string and an Integer. Then check the length of that string against the integer provided.

```
#import "NSObject+CountRRR.h"

@implementation NSObject (CountRRR)


-(BOOL)lengthOfName:(NSString *) sentence: (NSInteger *) number {
    return [sentence length]==number;
}
@end
```

Is the above method correct ?

How to call this particular method from the `ViewController`.

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "NSObject+CountRRR.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     NSString * name =@"Hi my name is James";
   // HOW TO CALL THE ABOVE METHOD HERE. ??????
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would just be

```
BOOL myBool = [name lengthOfName:name sentence:12];
```

however you shouldn't have (NSInteger *) it should be (NSInteger). Also might be better to make it a class method.

```
+(BOOL)lengthOfName:(NSString *) sentence: (NSInteger *) number;
```

Then at least you can do

```
BOOL myBool = [NSObject lengthOfName:name sentence:12];
```

Even better yet don't create a category for NSObject. Instead make one for UITextField or NSString. This isn't something you want for all NSObject it is just for checking the length of a string for a UITextField.

Hopefully that helps.

Edit

Also didn't notice this at first but your method name isn't formatted correctly to start.

Try

```
-(BOOL)lengthOfName:(NSString *)sentence withNumber:(NSInteger)number
```

Then your method call would be like...

```
BOOL myBool = [NSObject lengthOfName:name withNumber:12];
```

Comment: I get this Warming `'sentence' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector`

Comment: What is the line of code that is causing the issue?

Comment: nvm I saw where the issue is coming from. See the edit to my answer.